# Android OnTouch.ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android

I am using the OnTouchListener MotionEvent to design a button

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            tx.setText("Hello World");
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            tx.setText("WAIT.");
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tx.setText("OKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOK");
                }
            },2000);

            return true;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            tx.setText("Hello World");
        }
        return false;
```

TextView : "Hello World" (no press) > "WAIT" (pressing) > "OKOK..." (pressing > 2s)

if press the button <2s and release it

TextView : "Hello World" (no press) > "WAIT" (pressing) > "Hello World"(Action up) > "OKOKO..."

How to cancel the changing, when <2s and release the button?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        Timer timer = null;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                tx.setText("Hello World");
                if(timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                tx.setText("WAIT.");
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+event.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                    tx.setText("OKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOK");
                                    timer.cancel();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 2000, 2000);
                return true;
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                tx.setText("Hello World");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: if I click the button quickly(like action down, up, down, up..), the problem still appear...